# iphone : can't get edited image in uiimagepickercontroller after zooming with type camera

Tags: iphone, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, zooming

i am pretty stuck in middle of something
i am trying one demo app for `UIImagePickerController` type camera, and trying to zoom-in/out with camera overlay view using transform scaling matrix.

Well i have done zoom-in/out successfully, but now i want to get captured image in `UIimageView`, i am getting original image in

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker1 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

delegate method but cant get zoomed/scaled edited image into the `UIImageView`.
So here i have searched lot, but cant get rid of it, i hope you guys will help me out.

your help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. Retrieve the edited image from the
   info dictionary. Key: UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage
2. If that doesn't work, there is more
   info in the dictionary: UIImagePickerControllerCropRect

This is in the delegate method: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *) info
I assume that you know how to get a image into the imageview.